# Problem building package that needs opencv

Tags: opencv, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm getting an error during catkin make that I can't seem to get past.

I made sure to install ros-groovy-opencv2, yet I don't seem to have the opencv2Config.cmake file.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the error:

```
==> add_subdirectory(img_sender)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package): Could not find a configuration file for package opencv2.

Set opencv2_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for opencv2.  The file will have one of the following names:

opencv2Config.cmake
opencv2-config.cmake
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99906/problem-building-package-that-needs-opencv/) by [Brad](https://answers.ros.org/users/2761/brad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Brad,
In CMakeLists.txt of your package, do you have lines as follows?

find_package(OpenCV)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(my_awesome_library ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

---

Originally posted by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) with karma: 167 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Egnatius](https://answers.ros.org/users/10096/egnatius/) on 2013-12-19**:
Hi cognitiveRobot, I have a question regarding find_package(OpenCV).
Because when I use rospack find OpenCV, it says there is no such package
Yet I do found this this folder at /opt/ros/hydro/include/OpeCV
with  opencv2Config.cmake and  opencv2-config.cmake two files
and there is indeed no package.xml here
So what exactly is OpenCV here if it's not a package?

**Comment by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on 2014-03-23**:
OpenCV is a conventional library that is packaged as ROS package opencv2 for convenience of installation.